# Write a routine to print the numbers 1 to 6 and back to 1 again without using any loops

Tags: recursion, java

Can anyone help with this question? I currently have this solution that prints

> 1 2 3 4 5 6

but I'm having trouble going back down to 1.

```
public class noLoop{

     public static void main(String []args){
        noLoop(6);
     }

     public static void noLoop(int n) {

         if (n == 0) {
             return;
         }

         else {
             noLoop(n-1);
             System.out.println(n);
         }
     }
}
```

Comment: Can’t you just print the string 1 2 3 4 5 6 5 4 3 2 1?

Comment: This is a Java programming question, hence it is off-topic here on CS.SE. Also, the programming-languages tag is not appropriate for programming questions. Community: please, let's avoid answering off-topic questions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I understand, this problem is NOT about just printing "1 2 3 4 5 6 6 5 4 3 2 1" or "1 2 3 4 5 6 5 4 3 2 1". The number 6 is just to give an example of an integer.

Since noLoop is not successful, it is only natural to use a second recursion method. So noLoop and noLoop2 will do the job.

If you have to use one recursion method, an extra parameter such as `StringBuilder result` might be needed to store what we got so far. That is how noLoop3 comes. (Another way is to use a static variable instead of the extra parameter. I will let you to figure that out.)

```java
public class NoLoop {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        noLoop(6);
        noLoop2(6 - 1);

        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        noLoop3(6, sb);
        System.out.println(sb);
    }

    public static void noLoop(int n) {
        if (n > 0) {
            noLoop(n - 1);
            System.out.println(n);
        }
    }

    public static void noLoop2(int n) {
        if (n > 0) {
            System.out.println(n);
            noLoop2(n - 1);
        }
    }

    public static void noLoop3(int n, StringBuilder result ) {
        if (n > 0) {
            result.insert(0, n).append(n);
            noLoop3(n - 1, result);
        }
    }
}
```

By the way, this question borders on programming, which is [off-topic here](https://cs.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic). Please consider posting this kind of question to Stackoverflow later on.

Answer (score 3):

```
public class Foo {
    public static void main(String[] java_is_silly) {
        System.out.print("1 2 3 4 5 6 5 4 3 2 1");
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

This is clearly a Computer Science problem to demonstrate functional programming and recursion.  It needs action on the head and tail of recursion and a middle exit.

Those who only program without applying Computer Science would not approach it that way and would get poor marks from me!

```
// Recursion demonstration in Java
class NoLoop
{
    public static void main(String [] args) 
    {
        doit(1);
        System.out.println();
    }

    static void doit(int i)
    {
      System.out.print(i + " ");
      if (i >= 6) return;
      doit(i+1);
      System.out.print(i + " ");
    }
}
```